# TLS version 1.2 failed to open Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, windows, crystal-reports, tls1.2

Production server running Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition and Crystal Reports version 13.0.21.2533; previously the reports were working fine, but after disabling TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, SSL and enabling TLS 1.2, the reports failed with error message "Database logon failed".

Solution enable to view reports on browser

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your database connectivity method/driver to one that supports that newer standard.  Most likely, if you include the name of that method or driver in your web search, you'll find specific suggestions.
If you are using SQL Server as the data source, update to ***SQL Native 11 client***.